# How to sign a Azure AD user into Firebase in a Flutter mobile app?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, azure-active-directory

For a Flutter mobile app I am trying to use a Microsoft OAuthProvider to get a Firebase credential with which to sign the user into Firebase with their Azure AD account.

The closest I got was using a [third party Active Directory auth package](https://pub.dev/packages/aad_oauth) to log the user in and get an access token. However the sign-in to Firebase fails with an error message that suggests the idToken is invalid.

```dart
final AadOAuth oauth = new AadOAuth(config);
await oauth.login();

// accessToken looks legit
String accessToken = await oauth.getAccessToken();

String idToken = await oauth.getIdToken();

OAuthProvider provider = OAuthProvider('microsoft.com');

// Also tried the constructor without the idToken
OAuthCredential credential = provider.credential(accessToken: accessToken, idToken: idToken);

// app fails here:
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);

// this works fine, but only on web platform:
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithPopup(provider);
```

Because it is a platform specific error (iOS in this case), the exception details are not surfaced. All I get is:

> PlatformException(internal-error, ) nativeErrorCode: 17999

Here is my app settings in the Azure portal:

[image: screenshot]

Full manifest [here](https://gist.github.com/JannieT/e482eb97fc93f74733d5089017433fb4)

Has anyone been successful in using Microsoft Auth to sign a user in to Firebase in a Flutter mobile app?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the reason of your issue. Please check if your `config` includes `openid`, which will return the id token.

Comment: Can you include the error message and how you are defining `config`?

Comment: Thanks Allen, adding the openid to the scope did return a valid id token, but the app still fails on the same line with error code 17999. Updating my question.

Comment: did you get the solution? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @RMRAHUL have you tried Paurakh's answer? It worked for me.

Comment: Any solution using `aad_oauth`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Firebase Auth OAuth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth_oauth) package for it.

And sign in to the firebase using the Microsoft Auth provider.

```dart
User user = await FirebaseAuthOAuth().openSignInFlow(
  "microsoft.com", ["email openid"], {'tenant': 'your-tenent-id'});
```

This integrates nicely with firebase so, firebase `authStateChange` also works with this method.

Comment: Is there a way to use the data using this library to get a Microsoft Access token so that I can access MS Graph?

Comment: Where do I get the tenant ID?

Comment: Using this I get the error here - https://github.com/amrfarid140/firebase_auth_oauth/issues/49. Can anyone help?

Comment: @MateusFelipe you get your tenant id by going to the [tenant properties in your azure](https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/TenantPropertiesBlade)

Comment: When using this option i receive the error of 
 `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'auth')`
Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

You have just to not receiving idToken, just verify that you have add the id_token for the response_type and also openid scope like

```
provider.addScope('openid');
```

Also check weather you have allowed implicit flow with id token in the Azure portal app settings (you sould check ID tokens on the Authentication tab under Implicit grant section).

[image]

Comment: I am building a mobile app. The implicit grant flow is only available for a web app. I tried creating a web client and ticking those two boxes and including the openid scope, but the flow still fails on exactly the same line with the same error.

Comment: have you tried `provider.credential` with only idToken?

Comment: and do you use Azure B2C directory or regular Azure?

Comment: I don't use B2C and constructing the credential with just the id token fails on the same step, but with a slightly different error message: `error code: internal-error`

Answer (score 0):

Ok than have you added Microsoft as a authentication provider in the firebase authentication configuration Sign-in method page? And also have you tried to authenticate with Auth, after getCredentials method as stated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/microsoft-oauth?authuser=0)?

```
provider.getCredentialWith(nil) { credential, error in
  if error != nil {
    // Handle error.
  }
  if credential != nil {
    Auth().signIn(with: credential) { authResult, error in
      if error != nil {
        // Handle error.
      }
      // User is signed in.
      // IdP data available in authResult.additionalUserInfo.profile.
      // OAuth access token can also be retrieved:
      // authResult.credential.accessToken
      // OAuth ID token can also be retrieved:
      // authResult.credential.idToken
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

firebase authentication package has a method called signInWithPopup so you don't need firebase_auth_oauth anymore. here my code:

```
Future<UserCredential?> loginWithMicrosoft() async {
  OAuthProvider provider = OAuthProvider('microsoft.com');
  provider.setCustomParameters({
          "tenant": "your-tenant-id",
        });
  provider.addScope('user.read');
  provider.addScope('profile');
  try {
    final userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithPopup(provider);
    return userCredential;
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch(err) {
    debugPrint(err.message);
    // Handle FirebaseAuthExceptions
    // ex: firebase_auth/account-exists-with-different-credential
  }
}
```

Remeber add the redirect URI and enable de scopes in Azure Portal.

Comment: Not supported for mobile app