Firebase Authentication via Microsoft in FlutterApp
I am trying to authenticate user with microsoft at my firebase flutter app.
For Web Platforms the officially documented (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/federated-auth?hl=de) code works perfectly well.
However when trying to login on a mobile device i get the error:
Unable to process request due to missing initial state.
This may happen if browser session Storage is inaccessible or accidentally cleared. Some specific scenarios are - 1) Using IDP-Initiated SAML SSO. 2) Using signInWithRedirect in a storage-partitioned browser environment.
Future<UserCredential> signInWithMicrosoft() async {
  final microsoftProvider = MicrosoftAuthProvider();
  if (kIsWeb) {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithPopup(microsoftProvider);
  } else {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithProvider(microsoftProvider);
  }
}

I am registering my application like this for mobile platforms:
await Firebase.initializeApp();

Did anybody have the same issue, if so how to solve this?
Thanks in Advance
Cheers

Check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64066566/how-to-sign-a-azure-ad-user-into-firebase-in-a-flutter-mobile-app
